# React component complaining about SVG gradient styling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to turn an SVG into a react component, so I can use it multiple locations.

This is the source

```
<svg height="1000px" width="1000px" class="logo-triangle">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(50,50,50);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:black;stop-opacity:1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
        <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <polygon points="500 474,0 106,495 0" stroke="#36e2f8" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

However react does not seem to like the `linearGradient` segment of the SVG.

In particular these two lines:

```
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(50,50,50);stop-opacity:1"/>
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:black;stop-opacity:1"/>
```

The app will not work unless I delete those two lines, any idea how I can make this work with the JSX compiler?

This is the Error output from console:

> ×
>   The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX. This DOM node was rendered by `Logo`.

Comment: what happens if you set the stop-color as a mapped attribute and omit the stop-opacity altogether (since 1 is the default). i.e stop using the style parameter here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states the value of the `style` property should be an object and not a string

Try this:

```
<stop offset="0%" style={{stopColor:"rgb(50,50,50)", stopOpacity:1}} />
<stop offset="100%" style={{stopColor:"black", stopOpacity:1}} />
```